# Pass Value to One Script to Another in Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, send

Currently, I'm trying to add / subtract value from one script to another.  I wanted script one to add +125 health to script two but don't know how.  There is no gameobject involved in this scenarios.

Script one is

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class AddHealth : MonoBehaviour {

    int health = 10;

    public void ChokeAdd()

    {
        AddHealthNow();
    }

    public void AddHealthNow()
    {
        health += 125;
        Debug.Log("Added +125 Health");
    }
}
```

Script two is

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

namespace CompleteProject
{
    public class DataManager : MonoBehaviour

    {
        public static int depth;        
        public Text BOPPressureText;
        int health = 20;

        void Awake ()

        {
            depth = 0 ;
        }

        void Update ()
        {
            BOPPressureText.text = depth + 7 * (health) + " psi ";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "There is no gameobject involved in this scenarios." That's a pretty big claim when you're working in Unity, and very important. How did you make these components without associating them with a gameobject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to add health to your second script, declare your `health` field as public. So that you can access its value in your first script.

```
public int health;
```

But I wouldn't do stuff like that. Expose this field by a property like:

```
public int Health 
{
 get 
   {
    return this.health;
   }
 set 
   {
    this.health = value;
   }
}
```

by default the health will be declared as

```
private int health;
```

Other scripts can't access private fields.
Also you need a reference to your second script. You can access this via:

```
public DataManager data;
```

You've to assign your second object into this field in your Unity Editor. Then 
This way, you can access the field `health`by calling `data.health += 125` in your first script.

I don't know the specific thing in Unity, but I think you can also call your script by:

```
DataManager data = GetComponent<DataManager>();
data.health += 125;
```

Other method to get your other script is call it like that in your first script:

```
var secondScript = GameObject.FindObjectOfType(typeof(DataManager)) as DataManager;
secondScript.health += 125;
```

Comment: I having some errors adding DataManager data = GetComponent<DataManager>(); on the second script.

Comment: Do you have a reference to your first script, is it in the same namespace, if not considering adding it to your usings.

Comment: No, it doesn't have any reference.

Comment: I'm currently getting this error "The type or namespace name `DataManager' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?"

Comment: If you're using Visual studio try right clicking and "Resolving". Otherwise add a reference to your second script inside your first.

Comment: Ok.  I will give it a try.  Thanks.

Comment: In Unity3d, you don't ever call a constructor of a class which inherited from MonoBehavior. That is improper. Do not declare public variables either except for access through the Unity Editor.

Comment: Look at the edited post. You've several options to get your script. But expose your health field. Then use one of these methods, which I edited in the post.

Comment: Final got it to work!  Thanks!  I have to removed the namespace "Complete Project" first and use your 2nd method you have proposed.